# Why use the "and" in (funcall (and initial-major-mode))?

Tags: debugging

I came across this code today, and do not understand why the author used the "and" in it. As far as I can tell, these two lines deliver the same results and have the same functionality. The variable `initial-major-mode` is defined in `startup.el`, and holds the value of the initial major mode (lisp-interaction-mode for the *scratch* buffer).

```
(funcall (and initial-major-mode))
(funcall initial-major-mode)
```

Am I missing some nuance why the "and" is useful or required in the code? The only thing I can think of is that it might be an easy way of protecting against a `(funcall nil)` error if the `initial-major-mode` is undefined. But since it's a system variable, I would guess that it is always defined?

Comment: I do not think it is used deliberately. It looks as if left over  from debugging. I'm not aware of any way and could have any effect here.

Comment: In Emacs 24.5.1 2016-06-04 this string looks like `(funcall initial-major-mode)`, so @lunaryorn are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an "answer" just to clear the question. Everyone, including me when I posted the question, thinks that the "and" has no value, and might be a leftover from something.